# react-native-fbsdk - how to get user profile?

Tags: facebook, react-native

onLoginFinished's result just tells me the granted permissions. From the [repo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk), not clear how to get the user profile. Seems like react-native-fbsdkcore should wrap FBSDKProfile.h but don't see where it does.

```
 var FBSDKLogin = require('react-native-fbsdklogin');
    var {
      FBSDKLoginButton,
    } = FBSDKLogin;

    var Login = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        return (
          <View>
            <FBSDKLoginButton
              onLoginFinished={(error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                  alert('Error logging in.');
                } else {
                  if (result.isCanceled) {
                    alert('Login cancelled.');
                  } else {
                    alert('Logged in.');
                  }
                }
              }}
              onLogoutFinished={() => alert('Logged out.')}
              readPermissions={[]}
              publishPermissions={['publish_actions']}/>
          </View>
        );
      }
    });
```

Comment: I found solution for this, Here is solution : 

    const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');

    const {
  LoginButton,
  AccessToken,
  GraphRequest,
  GraphRequestManager,
  } = FBSDK;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383888/how-to-use-graph-api-with-react-native-fbsdk

Answer (score 4):

Found out you can get logged in user's profile with Graph API.

```
// Create a graph request asking for user's profile
var fetchProfileRequest = new FBSDKGraphRequest((error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    alert('Error making request.');
  } else {
    // Data from request is in result
  }
}, '/me');
// Start the graph request.
fetchProfileRequest.start();
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an easier way to do it. Rather than manually making the graph request yourself, 'react-native-fbsdkcore' package to get the data associated with the logged in user (if there is one)

var

```
 FBSDKCore = require('react-native-fbsdkcore');

var {
  FBSDKAccessToken,
} = FBSDKCore;

FBSDKAccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken((token) => {
  // token will be null if no user is logged in, 
  // or will contain the data associated with the logged in user
});
```

cphackm address is that in this [issue #2](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/2)

Comment: How do we use the answer to get the users name , email etc. Thanks

Comment: I don't believe that the FBSDK holds all the user information. You could easily use a graph request to pull the info that you need then store it local storage, or some other state.

Answer (score 0):

Using @flow, here is a full example:

**FbLogin.js**

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { LoginButton, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';
import { FbService } from '@services';
import { toast } from '@libs/helpers';

type LoginResult = {
    isCancelled: boolean,
    grantedPermissions?: Array<string>,
    declinedPermissions?: Array<string>
};

type Props = {
    store: {
        Account: Object
    }
};
type State = {
    token?: string
};

export default class Login extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    componentDidMount() {
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(tokenData => {
            if (tokenData) {
                console.log('[-- tokenData --]', tokenData);
                const { accessToken, userID } = tokenData;
                if (accessToken) {
                    console.log('[-- accessToken, userID --]', accessToken, userID);
                    this.setState({ token: accessToken });
                    // this._getUserInformation();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    _getUserInformation = () => {
        const { token } = this.state;
        const { Account } = this.props.store;

        if (token) {
            FbService.getFbUserData(token, (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('[-- error --]', error);
                } else {
                    Account.provider = 'facebook';
                    Account.authorized = true;
                    Account.current = { password: '', token, ...result };
                    console.log('[-- responseFbUserData --]', result);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <LoginButton
                    readPermissions={['public_profile']}
                    onLoginFinished={(error: Object, result: LoginResult) => {
                        if (error) {
                            alert('Login failed with error: ' + error.toString());
                        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                            alert('Login was cancelled');
                        } else {
                            if (result) {
                                this._getUserInformation();
                            }
                        }
                    }}
                    onLogoutFinished={() => toast('User logged out', 'info')}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

/* AccessToken
accessToken: string,
applicationID: string,
userID: string,
permissions: Array<string>,
declinedPermissions: Array<string>,
accessTokenSource?: string,
expirationTime: number,
lastRefreshTime: number,
*/
```

**FbService.js**

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import { GraphRequestManager, GraphRequest, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';

export function getFbUserData(token: string, callBack: Function) {
    const profileRequestConfig = {
        httpMethod: 'GET',
        version: 'v2.12',
        parameters: {
            fields: {
                string: 'id, name, email'
            }
        },
        accessToken: token
    };

    const profileRequest = new GraphRequest('/me', profileRequestConfig, callBack);
    new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(profileRequest).start();
}
```